# How to freez black and allow to play white in chessboard.js and chess.js

Tags: chessboard.js

How Can I run a chess game in chessboard.js and chess.js, but allow only white player to move pieces?
I need to make it was always white turn. If I move white side I want to make another move by white side.

I want to make a "chess moves game" where white side should wipe out all black pieces, for example only in 5 moves. That's why I want to make white side to play as in normal game, but black side staying still (never get a turn, no draggable).

Answer (score 1):

This question more concerns `chess.js` than `chessboard.js`, as `chess.js` is the chess engine you're using.

**Doing this will destroy the game history.**

First of all you can override the `onDragStart` for the board, something like:

```
var onDragStart = function(source, piece, position, orientation) {  
    // if it's not white, don't allow drag
    if (piece.search(/^w/) === -1) ||
        return false;
    }
};

var cfg = {
  draggable: true,
  position: 'start',
  onDragStart: onDragStart
};
var board = ChessBoard('board', cfg);
```

Second you have you have to force the turn.

1. If you reload the game by taking the position in FEN and `load`ing the FEN to the board with the side to move set to W, you'll get your desired behavior.
2. You could edit the source of `chess.js` a bit, https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/issues/62 like in that issue. The author posted this snippet or here:

   ```
   /* totally untested ... this will blow your game state/history  */
   function set_turn(chess, color) {
       var tokens = chess.fen().split(' ');
       tokens[1] = color;
       chess.load(tokens.join(' '));
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

My version of Chessboard JS is v.1.0.0.

The best way to do this is using [Chessboard.js events](https://chessboardjs.com/docs).

When passing the configuration to the Chessboard object (on initialization) you can specify callback functions which will be called when certain events take place in the board.

In order to allow/prevent a player from moving a piece we need to specify a callback for onDragStart and return a value of true to allow the action and false if not.

For instance we can check who the user is or if any flags are turned on.

Also there are several arguments passed to the onDragStart function to help you decide whether or not to let the user move the piece.

Just return false to prevent the move and true to allow it.

For example:

```
const chessboardConfig = {
    position: 'start',
    draggable: true,
    onDragStart: onDragStart,
};

// Create chessboard and chess obj
const board = window.Chessboard('elementDomID', chessboardConfig);

function onDragStart(source, piece, position, orientation) {
    // Validate side moving piece
    return !((orientation === 'white' && piece.search(/^w/) === -1) ||
                (orientation === 'black' && piece.search(/^b/) === -1));
}
```